# Linq Multiple Joins and Group By

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So I'm not even sure if what i'm doing is possible, but i'm basically trying to take 4 different lists, join them into 1 object.

The only thing is, the `orderLineItems` will be a collection and I can't quite figure out the best way to get it into the appropriate list item. I know i probably need to do a group by, but the group by seems to break the assignments when i do the Select

**One thing to clarify:** The challenge is getting the LineItems - if I do not assign the line items and remove any lineitem reference from the query the data populates properly, however, since the lineitems are a collection I can't figure out the proper way to assign them in the Select - hope that makes sense..

```
var ordersa = (from order1 in orderList
  join person in customerAccountPeople
       on order1.CustomerAccountPersonId equals person.CustomerAccountPersonId
  join subject in subjectList
       on order1.SubjectId equals subject.SubjectId
  from orderLineItem in orderLineItemList
  join order in orderList
       on orderLineItem.OrderId equals order.OrderId
  group orderLineItem by orderLineItem.OrderId into orderLineItems
  select new OrderList()
  {
      Customer = person,
      Subject = subject,
      Order = order1,
      LineItems = orderLineItems
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Did you try using the `Include()` method?

Comment: I always say: "If you think to write a complex LINQ query, you probably should be writing a stored procedure instead!".

Comment: There is undoubtedly someone who can create a single monster linq statement for you here on SO. For my part however, I find that it makes for more readable code to break these statements down into bits.  All execution is reserved until that final `ToList()` call, so there is no penalty for smaller queries.  Allows for easier testing as well.

Comment: These lists have all been pulled independently from the database already. They have already been "ToList()'d" - I just need to rejoin the data into this new object. I can't use include, these data set is massive and i've narrowed down the precise fields I need so that to decrease the time it takes to execute/return the data.

Comment: Also, the database was created prior to moving to EF. So there are some   issues with the DB (that cannot be changed at this time) which prevent me from doing ALL the filtering prior to "ToList()" it. That is why i am separating the data out into individual lists, then rejoining. The performance is much faster this way than prior, I just need to figure out how to rejoin the lineitems back into that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current solution, you're basically joining each line item with it's order, subject and person, then grouping the resulting list by order id. Which is not what you want: you want the order, subject and person together with a list of line items.

You should do the grouping of the line items beforehand. Since you clarified that everything is in memory, you can work with an `ILookup` of the order line items by order id:

```
 // GroupBy works just as well
 var orderLineItemsByOrderId = orderLineItemList.ToLookup(ol => ol.OrderId);
 var ordersa = (
     from order1 in orderList
     join person in customerAccountPeople
     on order1.CustomerAccountPersonId equals person.CustomerAccountPersonId
     join subject in subjectList
     on order1.SubjectId equals subject.SubjectId
     let orderLineItems = orderLineItemsByOrderId[order1.OrderId]
     select new 
     {
         Customer = person,
         Subject = subject,
         Order = order1,
         LineItems = orderLineItems
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var ordersa = (from order1 in orderList
                   join person in customerAccountPeople
                        on order1.CustomerAccountPersonId equals person.CustomerAccountPersonId
                   join subject in subjectList
                        on order1.SubjectId equals subject.SubjectId
                   select new OrderList()
                   {
                       Customer = person,
                       Subject = subject,
                       Order = order1,
                       LineItems =    ( from orderLineItem in orderLineItemList
                                           join order in orderList
                                                on orderLineItem.OrderId equals order1.OrderId
                                           group orderLineItem by orderLineItem.OrderId into orderLineItems )
                   }).ToList();
```